# unable to communicate with service

Tags: ros, household-objects-database, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey ,I get this error :

ERROR: Unable to communicate with service [/objects_database_node/get_model_list], address [rosrpc://grasp.willowgarage.com:15432]

when I tried to add model sets to my DB "household_objects_database"
using this command :
rosservice call /objects_database_node/get_model_list REDUCED_MODEL_SET

,roscore was running too .

I'm using furete with Ubuntu 11.10

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57674/unable-to-communicate-with-service/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, we are no longer supporting remote access to a database server hosted at Willow Garage. Instructions for installing the household_objects_databaselocally  are provided here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/household_objects_database

---

Originally posted by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) with karma: 586 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-21**:
I have already followed these instructions ,but I have an error at the last command :
rosservice call /objects_database_node/get_model_list REDUCED_MODEL_SET

Telling me that :
ERROR: Service [/objects_database_node/get_model_list] is not available.